# Scala JDBC Connection to Cloudera VM mysql

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc

how to connect to mysql based on cloudera quickstat vm from scala? I can connect to vm using:

```
ssh cloudera@172.16.206.142
```

and able to launch mysql. but not able to establish connection from scala JDBC connection manager.

I tried this but its not working

```
val url = "jdbc:mysql://cloudera@172.16.206.145:3306/retail_db"
val username = "retail_dba"
val password = "cloudera"
```

Comment: What error do you get? As it could be a missing driver, a firewall... or anything in between.

Comment: Error : Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: cloudera@172.16.206.145: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: The jdbc url is wrong. Try `jdbc:mysql://172.16.206.145:3306/retail_db`

Comment: Thanks! this worked.